# C++ OOP problem, cant understand why I am getting access violation

Tags: c++, class, oop

I am new to C++ and trying to create some kind of small casino for a school project,
I have the following classes: Game.h, Deck.h, Card.h, Player.h

I have a function that populates the deck, which calls another function called "AddCard" which is within Deck.h.

my problem is I created an array of cards in Deck class and it has the size of 52. when im running in a for loop to populate the deck its succesfuly adds the first item and than when trying to add deck[1] it says stackoverflow.

my code is the following:
Deck constructor:

```
const int maxSize = 52;
Deck:: Deck() {
    amountOfCards = 0;
    deck = new Card[maxSize];
}
```

addCard function where it fails:

```
void Deck::addCard(Card & c) {
    if (!isFull())
    {
        deck[amountOfCards] = c;
        amountOfCards++;
    }
}
```

My Initialize deck code:

```
Card* C;
    //Initialize Deck
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 2; j < 11; j++)
        {
            C = new Card(j, Card::symbol(i), _T("Test"));
            this->mainDeck.addCard(*C);
        }
        Card *jack = new Card(11, Card::symbol(i), _T("JACK"));
        this->mainDeck.addCard(*jack);
        Card* queen = new Card(12, Card::symbol(i), _T("QUEEN"));
        this->mainDeck.addCard(*queen);
        Card* king = new Card(13, Card::symbol(i), _T("KING"));
        this->mainDeck.addCard(*king);
        Card* ace = new Card(14, Card::symbol(i), _T("ACE"));
        this->mainDeck.addCard(*ace);
    }
```

and the exception is:
Exception thrown at 0x78A40BBA (mfc140ud.dll) in FinalProject.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFDFDFDF9.

I would love to get some help, thanks!

Edit:

IsFull function:

```
bool Deck::isFull() {
    if (amountOfCards == 52)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

The Initialize deck happens in Game.cpp constructor:

```
Game::Game(Player& p1, Player& p2) {
    this->players[0] = p1;
    this->players[1] = p2;
    this->turn = 0;
    this->isGameOver = false;
    this->mainDeck = new Deck();
    Card* C;
    //Initialize Deck
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 2; j < 11; j++)
        {
            C = new Card(j, Card::symbol(i), _T("Test"));
            this->mainDeck.addCard(*C);
        }
        Card *jack = new Card(11, Card::symbol(i), _T("JACK"));
        this->mainDeck.addCard(*jack);
        Card* queen = new Card(12, Card::symbol(i), _T("QUEEN"));
        this->mainDeck.addCard(*queen);
        Card* king = new Card(13, Card::symbol(i), _T("KING"));
        this->mainDeck.addCard(*king);
        Card* ace = new Card(14, Card::symbol(i), _T("ACE"));
        this->mainDeck.addCard(*ace);
    }
}
```

Deck class variables

```
class Deck:public Card
{
private:
    int amountOfCards;
    Card* deck;
```

I think my Card array isnt initalized right.. like its not getting allocated .. its only able to add 1 item to this array and than crash.

Comment: Is there a reason you're insisting upon using raw pointers instead of just an `std::vector`? Also, can we get the full implementation of `Deck` and wherever that "initialize deck code" is being run?

Comment: ```void Deck::addCard(Card & c) {....``` you probably want to pass by pointer and not by referrence

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Is `isFull` correctly implemented? You can use something like this https://godbolt.org/z/8vEcW7 .

Comment: @mag_zbc How do you know that it writes out of bounds? As long as `isFull()` does something equivalent to `return amountOfCards < maxSize;` it should be good.

Comment: also you have memory leaks. Do not use explicit `new` operator, learn how to use `std::vector`, `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared`.

Comment: value `0xFDFDFDF9` indicates use of uninitialized pointer. Your code doesn't have anything like this, so error is in place which you didn't shown.

Comment: I have edited the post with more code.. thanks for your suggestions still didnt find the solution.. I prefer to fix it this way instead of using std::vector becuase we have to use what we learnt in class..

Comment: Why are you using pointers at all? What are they doing for you?